# Get required values from multiline string python

Tags: python, parsing, filter, pattern-matching

I have the following string in python:

```
Data sent by: zabbix

The production server prod1 is unavailable

https://zabbix.com/link/to/zabbix/dashboard

Environment: prod1
Dep: dev
```

How can i get Environment and Dep from that string to generate url from them? I tried to go line by line but it seems not a good solution. Please help i'm novice in python. Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your expected output - what's the URL you hope to create?

Comment: for example: https://zabbix.com/link/to/zabbix/dashboard/dev/prod1
i tried re.search but any of my attempts doesn't work

Comment: The lines are always in that same order?

Comment: yes, the order is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, going through line by line isn't wrong. Another option is to use regex

```
import re
text = '''Data sent by: zabbix

The production server prod1 is unavailable

https://zabbix.com/link/to/zabbix/dashboard

Environment: prod1
Dep: dev'''

env = re.search(r'Environment: (.+)', text).group(1)
dep = re.search(r'Dep: (.+)', text).group(1)
url = 'zabbix.com/link/to/zabbix/dashboard/{}/{}'.format(dep, env)
```